# When to add \0 to an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble determining when to set the '\0' in case of a string or an array in C.

**Example :** 
If I defined an array with `char tab[20]` in order to avoid buffer overflow, when should I add the '\0'?

```
tab[20] = 0;
```

or

```
tab[19]= 0;
```

Comment: For *any* array, what is the valid range of indexes?

Comment: The valid range is from 0 and (in my case) 19.

Comment: So what do you think would happen if you use `20` as index? Remember that an array of characters is no different than any other array.

Comment: Typical, If I need to declare a array to store 20 items and I will do it like `tab[20 + 1]`

Comment: That's problem I'm having. I have a code that I'm reviewing and the guy who has written this code has over 20 years experience with the C language and it made me doubt the things I already know.

Comment: @FrankAK If your "items" are something else than characters of a string, there is no need to add an extra byte.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah, you are right. But to save my life, I'd like to do that :)

Comment: Note that a 0 at the end only protects buffer overflows on read, e.g. in printf. Functions doing a write to an array should always have a length or size parameter and don't use the sentinel. (but frequently add one above and beyond the given size, e.g. scanf).

Answer (score 5):

For an array defined as `char tab[20]`, `tab[20]` is not a valid member (or, on other words, 20 is not a *valid* index). Remember, C arrays use 0-based indexing.

You can only access index from 0 to size-1, i.e, 0 to 19, in this case So, you got to add the [*sentinel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) in the last valid position, index 19.

That said, it is not *mandatory* to add the null terminator in the last member always. Based on the usage, you need to put the null terminator immediately after the last *valid* element. The max value of the index in this case is 19.

Consider the examples below:

```
char arr[20]; // local variable, not initialized , elements holds indeterminate value

arr[0] = 'H'
arr[1] = 'E'
arr[2] = 'L'
arr[3] = 'L'
arr[4] = 'O'
```

In this case, to use `arr` as a *string*, you need to put the null terminator at `arr[5]`.

However, for the below case

```
arr[0] = 'H'
arr[1] = 'E'
. . . 
arr[18] = 'E'
```

you need to put it in `arr[19]`, but that's it. Your *array* cannot hold any more  values and 19 is the last index you're allowed to access freely.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
char tab[20];
```

then `tab[0]` to `tab[19]` inclusive is valid.

So to guarantee that a C-string function will not overrun the buffer, you should write

```
tab[19] = 0;
```

Alternatively, you could initialise *all* the elements in the array to 0 with

```
char tab[20] = {0};
```

Note that you are able to read the *pointer* `tab + 20`, but you are not allowed to *dereference* it.

Comment: I wouldn't say you're able to "read" `tab+20`, either. "Compute", maybe.

Comment: @SteveSummit: No, reading the value of a pointer is adequate terminology; i.e. you can write `char* p = tab + 20;`

Comment: *I* understand that.  But I think most readers will be confused by your last sentence, because "read" sounds like a synonym for "read the value pointed to".

Comment: @SteveSummit: Surely not, given that I go on to say *deference*.

Comment: I still think you'll confuse people, but I won't argue with you any more.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overflow depends on the way how you utilize the buffer. For instance, if you call a function that plans to put 40 chars into your 20-char buffer, you'll end up with the buffer overflow for sure, regardless the fact have you pre-populated \0 char at the end or not.

So, rules of thumb:

- Once using a buffer as a parameter, always pass both pointer to the buffer and the length of the buffer. Called functions **must** respect the length you've provided.
- If called function expects a special char as a end-of-buffer marker (instead of the buffer length), you **must** place it before the function call. Different functions may expect different special chars, \0 or $ or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

When you use and some advance information related to '\0':

1. **Predefined string library** cause they need the character array which is ending with '\0'
2. **Buffer validity( End Of Buffer )** : at the time of parsing the string from one entity to another
3. **People use this** : when your code need to be merge with another one then you may need to use it

Comment: @David - `NULL` and `0` are *conceptually* not the same, but in C, `NULL` can be represented as integer zero (and in C++, it must be).  It *converts* to a pointer (specifically, the null pointer) in an appropriate context, but it's a whole can of pedantry to open.  Actually, your advice is probably most appropriate at the level of this Q+A: consider `NULL` to be something different to characters or integers.